# Error Processing LT in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I am writing my first ColdFusion component but I am getting this error.  Does anyone have an idea what this means?

```
Invalid CFML construct found on line 2 at column 1.
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:
<
The CFML compiler was processing:
< marks the beginning of a ColdFusion tag.Did you mean LT or LTE?
The error occurred in C:/inetpub/wwwroot/ColdFusion/test.cfm
<cfcomponent displayname="News" hint="Get News">
<cffunction name="GetNews" returntype="query">
<cfquery datasource="CFDatabase" name="myQuery"
```

The source code:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="News" hint="Get News">
<cffunction name="GetNews" returntype="query">
    <cfquery datasource="CFDatabase" name="myQuery">
        select * from tbNews
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn myQuery>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>

<cfinvoke component="components.News" method="GetNews" returnvariable="AllNews">

<table width="100%">
<cfoutput query="AllNews">
<tr>
    <td>Title:</td>
    <td><cfoutput>#myQuery.Title#</cfoutput></td>
    <td>Body:</td>
    <td><cfoutput>#myQuery.Description#</cfoutput></td>
</tr>
</cfoutput>
</table>
```

Comment: As an aside, be sure to localize/`var` scope all [function local variables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7dfb.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0ac4a-7fbd) - including queries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've placed the `<cfcomponent>` inside a cfm file, this i not allowed.

move the `<cfcomponent>` block to a file with a .cfc extension (eg News.cfc), then call it from your .cfm file

in News.cfc

```
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction name="getNews">
...
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

in test.cfm

```
<cfset newsObj = createobject('component', 'News')>
<cfset AllNews = newsObj.getNews()>
```

Comment: Thank you I am new to CFM and I am following an example that seamingly just threw it into the CFM Code.

Comment: and make sure he changes <cfoutput query="AllNews"> to <cfoutput query="qNews">

Comment: updated my answer to fit with the source code @TheMonkeyMan added to his question

Comment: The `<cfoutput>` inside of the `<cfoutput>` is also unneeded. #myQuery.Description# should just be #Description#

Comment: its always better to scope a variable than not. Whilst not technically required in this instance, it means the cfml engine has less searching to do when locating the scope for the variable. #variables.myquery.description# would be best

Comment: It's make my day brother. :)

Answer (score 2):

The error is in a file called test.cfm, and you're showing us code in a CFC, which isn't much help.

However the error message is fairly clear: you're using a `<` in the wrong place.  And it's on line 2 of test.cfm (or possibly a knock-on effect from something on line 1).

Can you update your question to post the actual code it's talking about?

But look at lines 1-2 and look for a syntax error.  Is there an expression in which you are doing a less-than evaluation, and you're using < instead of LT / LTE (as per the guidance in the error message...)

Comment: I think the <cfcomponent> is actually in test.cfm, which may well be the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Is CFComponent not allowed in the same file as the source.

Comment: No its not, see my answer below

Comment: Wow, I see.  OK, that's a bug in the CF compiler then if that's the error it's reporting.  It *should* be saying something to the effect of "<cfcomponent> is not allowed in a CFM file", given that's the actual problem. And this would have had the OP on the right track straight away! I've raised https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3364465 to cover this. It's not really the sort of thing I'd expect to be "fixed", though.

Comment: That was the problem.  I am used to the Compiler and Runtime in other languages telling me hey that's just wrong.  I think 'Target Invocation Thrown By Exception' in ASP.NET.

Comment: Perhaps Coldfusion should have like Adam Cameron said just tell me that I messed up.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error, and I found out I had a missing `>` (greater-than sign) at the end of one of my `cf` tags, which happened to be a `<cfif>`. So, I changed

```
<cfif condition EQ true</cfif>
```

to

```
<cfif condition EQ true></cfif>
```

Another time I ran into a similar problem with a `#` in a style attribute of an HTML element. Since it was in a `cfoutput`, ColdFusion tried to render what I meant as a hexadecimal color value - which begins with a hashtag - as a ColdFusion variable, but it wasn't closed with a second hashtag. So I changed the inline styles to an external stylesheet, which I honestly should have done in the first place :)